# Gauge symmetry of massive vector field

Tags: electromagnetism, field-theory, gauge-theory, classical-field-theory, gauge

Consider a real massive vector field with lagrangian density

$$\begin{align}\mathcal{L}&=-\frac{1}{4}(\partial_\mu A_\nu-\partial_\nu A_\mu)(\partial^\mu A^\nu-\partial^\nu A^\mu)+\frac{1}{2}m^2 A^\mu A_\mu\\&=-\frac{1}{2}(\partial_\mu A_\nu-\partial_\nu A_\mu)\partial^\mu A^\nu+\frac{1}{2}m^2 A^\mu A_\mu.\tag{1}\end{align}$$

Under a local gauge transformation $A_\mu\longrightarrow A_\mu+\partial_\mu f$ the lagrangian density is not invariant

$$\begin{align}\mathcal{L}\longrightarrow&~\mathcal{L}+\frac{1}{2}m^2\left(2A^\mu+\partial^\mu f\right)\partial_\mu f\\=&\,\mathcal{L}-\frac{1}{2}m^2f\left(2\partial_\mu A^\mu+\square f\right)\end{align}\tag{2}$$

unless we take an $f$ that satisfies $$\square f=-2\partial_\mu A^\mu\tag{3}.$$

---

Equations of motion for the vector field are

$$(\square+m^2) A^\mu-\partial^\mu\partial_\nu A^\nu=0,\tag{4}$$ and taking its divergence $\partial_\mu$ we obtain $$\partial_\mu A^\mu=0\tag{5}.$$

This identity is the Lorenz gauge, but it is satisfied automatically. Then, from $(3),$ $A_\mu\longrightarrow A_\mu+\partial_\mu f$ is a symmetry of the theory as long as $\square f=0$. Can this be considered a kind of "partial" or "reduced" gauge symmetry?

**Edit:** I realized one thing.

With $(5)$, the eom $(4)$ becomes
$$(\square+m^2)A_\mu=0,\tag{6}$$
but this equation is *not* invariant under the transformation $A_\mu\longrightarrow A_\mu+\partial_\mu f$ even if $\square f=0$. Why is this equation not invariant but the lagrangian density is?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Symmetries of the action must be considered *without use of the equations of motion*. An *on-shell symmetry* is a vacuous notion - if you use the equations of motion, as you do when using eq. (5) to conclude that $\square f = 0$ should be a symmetry, then *any* infinitesimal transformation of the action will leave the action invariant, precisely because the equations of motion mark a stationary point of the action, and the definition of a stationary point is more or less that all infinitesimal variations vanish. See also [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/614484/50583) and its linked answers by Qmechanic.
2. Precisely because symmetries must be considered off-shell, your eq. (3) is inconsistent. Since we are off-shell, $A^\mu$ is an arbitrary field not taking any specific values, but $f$ needs to be a fixed function. Since eq. (3) cannot be fulfilled off-shell for arbitrary $A^\mu$, there *is no gauge invariance of the action of a massive vector field*.
3. As discussed in [this answer of mine](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/176454/50583), the Hamiltonian theory of the massive vector field has two constraints:
   \begin{align}
   \pi^0 & \approx 0 \\
   \partial_i \pi^i + m^2 A_0 & \approx 0
   \end{align}
   The Poisson bracket of these constraints is non-vanishing, so they are both *second-class constraints*, but only first-class constraints can possibly generate gauge transformations, see points 4. and 5. in [this answer of mine](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/351241/50583). Therefore, the theory of the massive vector field is *constrained*, but it is not a *gauge theory*.