# Hessian matrix after the introduction of the gauge fixing term

Tags: quantum-field-theory, gauge-theory, propagator

I am studying a theory with a Lagrangian density that I don't want to write because I would like to try to tackle the problem by myself.
The fact is that it is a theory with two fields $\{ A_{\mu\nu},B_\mu \}$ where $A_{\mu\nu}$ is an anti-simmetric field and $B_\mu$ is a vector field.

I found that the action is invariant under a local transformation of the $A_{\mu\nu}$ field and then, to calculate the propagators, I introduce a gauge fixing term that breaks the symmetry which depends on field $A_{\mu\nu}$ and on a lagrange multiplier.

What I have found is that despite the breaking of the local symmetry the Hessian matrix to be inverted to calculate the propagators is still degenerate.

So my question is: is the Hessian matrix degenerate if and only if there is a local symmetry? Or is it possible that it is even if the action has no local symmetries?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/351104/50583, see in particular part 5 of my answer for the case of gauge-fixing

Comment: Thanks, i read your answer and it clarified many things to me. Coming to my example, I noticed that the only way to make the Hessian matrix invertible is to add a gauge fixing term even with field B which has no gauge invariance. How can i justify this?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you mean, but even a non-gauge vector field is a constrained system (just not a *gauge* theory) because your $B_\mu$ has 4 components but there are only three physical d.o.f. in a massive spin-1 particle. See also [this answer of mine](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/176454/50583)

Comment: Thank you! I am new to gauge theories and thought constrained systems were only those with local symmetry.